# R - when to drop a column based on missing data

Tags: r, missing-data

This questions is more regarding statistical theory, specifically as it pertains to binary classification modeling . When should I remove a column because of missing or uncollected data? As an example, is there a generally accepted practice? Like if more than 50% of the data is missing in a column then the whole column should go?

I have tried to look around and instead end up finding plenty of instruction on how to do it, like the code, not when to do it.

For more background I am working on a project where I am analyzing my company's clinic visits in an attempt to predict patient no-shows, and/or late cancels. Some of the data like race, preferred language, ethnicity etc have a lot of not specified, unknown, not collected, NA etc.

Comment: You should look at http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~gbrown/research/polikar10missing.pdf
This paper talks about effect of missing data on the performance and how can one accommodate missing data by random subspace selection.

Comment: @Gopal Srivastava, does it mention when to drop a whole column of data? Sorry, I am familiar with what you described already and am looking for very specific information.

Comment: I am not sure about the clinical data but when dealing with loans if a column has more than 50% of data missing then you drop that column.
Also, if you don't want to do this then you can replace missing values with median or frequency value for that column and then do feature selection. It is possible that those features would get eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to answer this question generally. It will depend on the type and objectives of the analysis and on the particulars of the data. Sometimes a partially observed variable is very useful, in which case the decision needs to be made based on domain knowledge. In cases when the variable is mostly missing and doesn't significantly change the results, you would probably omit it.

In your example, the trade-off would be that using more variables should (in large samples) lead to better predictions of cancellation/no-shows. But, as you include more variables in the model, there will be more patients with partially observed data who you won't be able to predict at all. If you found out that a variable that was only 30% observed was able to provide very accurate predictions, and without it the predictions were useless, I suspect you'd want to use it.